# Prevent bottom div shift after applying ng-animate on upper div

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have a top div with a title and a button and a bottom div with some text. When I click the button I want the bottom text to appear and the button to fade away over a period of one second. The behavior is working correctly but the problem is after the button disappears the head div becomes shorter and the bottom div is shifted upwards resulting in an unpleasant behavior.

My question is. how do I maintain the top div fixed in height even after the button disappears?

I can imagine there are many ways. I can put something unseen with the same height of the button to keep the space but it doesn't feel elegant. I can make the head div fixed height but it will not look the same on different screens and will not be as fluid.

What is the simple elegant way?

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1><span class="hometitle">title</h1>
    <button class="btn btn-primary animate-show" type="button" ng-click="ctrl.showPoll = true" ng-show="!ctrl.showPoll">click here to show question</button>
</div>

    <div class="row marketing">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <form name="votForm" ng-show="ctrl.showPoll" ng-controller="frmCtrl as frm" ng-submit="frm.addVote(votForm.$valid)" novalidate>
                <p>question</p>
                <input ng-model="frm.vote" type="radio" name="myVote" value="1" required>op 1<br>
                <input ng-model="frm.vote" type="radio" name="myVote" value="2">op 2<br>
                <input ng-model="frm.vote" type="radio" name="myVote" value="3">op 3<br>
                <input ng-model="frm.vote" type="radio" name="myVote" value="4">op 4.<br>
                <input type="submit" value="submit" name="click me" >
                <div class="panel" ng-show="frm.showError">Please select an option before submitting </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

js

```
app.controller('votCtrl', ['$cookies', function($cookies){
    var showPoll = false;
    this.hasVoted = $cookies.iVoted || "nustiu";

}]);
```

css

```
.animate-show {
    opacity: 1;
}

.animate-show.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active,
.animate-show.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
    -webkit-transition: all linear 1s;
    transition: all linear 1s;
}

.animate-show.ng-hide {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: can you show what you have done in jsfiddle

Comment: i put the actual code in the quesiton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not rely on `ng-hide` class. It's a built-in AngularJS class and it will literally **hide** your button, I mean it will add `display: none` to it. That's not what you want. Remove `ng-show` directive and add `ng-class`.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary animate-show" type="button" ng-click="ctrl.showPoll = true" ng-class="{'hidden-button': ctrl.showPoll}">click here to show question</button>
```

then in CSS:

```
.hidden-button {
  opacity: 0;

  -webkit-transition: all linear 1s;
  -moz-transition: all linear 1s;
  -ms-transition: all linear 1s;
  -o-transition: all linear 1s;
  transition: all linear 1s;
}
```

Comment: opacity: 0 is what i am doing and the bottom div with the questions jumps up

Comment: now the button disappears and the form does not move but the animation effect is gone. i want the button to fade away

Comment: @Patriot, another edit. Obviously you had to also move `transition` rules to the new class.

Comment: this is very good because now i don't even have to include the ng-animate dependency. Thanks